# How to display ActionSheet from master view in split view

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, master-detail

I’m using Xcode 6 on an iPad app targeted to iOS7. It’s a master-detail app with a button on each group header view in the master list. I would like the button to display an ActionSheet. I’m having trouble with the ActionSheet.

In order to get the ActionSheet to appear at all I have to pass it the SplitViewController’s view to display itself on:

```
UIActionSheet* menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@“Button 1”, @“Button 2“, nil];
UIView* view = [[[self appDelegate] splitViewController] view];
[menu showFromRect:[sender convertRect:[sender bounds] toView:nil] inView:view animated:YES];
```

Passing any other view (such as the TableView, a group header, or a button) generates an exception telling me that I’m trying to display the ActionSheet from a disconnected view. But displaying the ActionSheet this way allows the master view to maintain precedence in the responder chain (mostly):

- If the ActionView displays itself on the left side of the screen it displays under the master view. Only the portion to the right of the master view’s edge is visible.
- When the ActionSheet is displayed, if I tap one of its buttons the master view slides offscreen and the ActionSheet remains, as if I had not tapped it. Once the master view is gone, tapping an ActionSheet button calls that button’s method.
- When the ActionSheet is displayed, if I tap a cell in the master view nothing happens.
- When the ActionSheet is displayed, if I tap the detail view, the master view slides offscreen, leaving the ActionSheet displayed.

I’ve read several SO posts on disconnected views and ActionSheets. The table view’s `window` property is defined as the app’s window, so I think it’s in the view heirarchy. I haven’t found a property in the table view or its controller hierarchy that can cause the table view to become “connected”.

It just seems that if I could find the proper view to pass to the ActionSheet it would correct ActionSheet's behavior.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is your issue while in portrait or landscape? Try showing the action sheet from the view of the view controller in the master portion of the split view controller.

Comment: Same problems in both orientations. When I show the action sheet from the Table View, which is the master view, I get the disconnected view exception.